# Game Board always reset to initial state Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The exercise is to redo the game *Breakthrough* in Python; it's a Draughts-like game, with a board of *n* lines and *p* row.

I initiate my game board with this function:

```
def NewBoard(n,p):
    board = [["."] * p for i in range(n)]

    for i in range(0, 2):
        for j in range(0, p):
            board[i][j] = 'o'

    for k in range(n - 2, n):
        for l in range(0, p):
            board[k][l] = 'x'

    return board
```

But this always reset the board, because this function is the initial state of the game.

When I try to do the main game function, every time the player changes, the board is reseting itself:

```
def Breaktrough(n, p):
    DisplayBoard(NewBoard(n,p))
    DisplayBoard(Where(NewBoard(n, p), 1, *SelectPawn(1)))
    DisplayBoard(Where(NewBoard(n, p), 2, *SelectPawn(2)))
```

I tried some solutions that I thought were good but weren't.

Comment: So what solutions did you try, why were they no good?

Comment: Sorry for the horrible english, it's not my native langage.
I tried to do a function that would take as an arg the board returned by NewBoard, and return it again. But that didn't work, i just created a function that did no modification on the board ahah.
But thanks to John Coleman i got my answer! Thanks a lot. It was so simple i did not even think of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a board to a variable so that you can refer to the same board over time, not repeatedly create new boards at every (attempted) move. In the main function, have the line

```
board = NewBoard(n,p)
```

It won't be "reset" automatically (unless you call `NewBoard()` again). In the rest of the code, refer to `board` rather than `NewBoard(n,p)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So simple and yet i did not think of it. My bad ahah.